# How do I create a conditional query that has optional $in with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return a list of documents that match a, or b, or c conditions.

Right now, I can only get it to work by matching ALL conditions, not just one...

I have tried this:

```
return User
    .find()
    .where({ $or: [
        { $in: skillTags },
        { $in: roleTags }
    ]})
```

But I get an error.

This one works but is not what I want as it only returns results that match both a skillTag and a roleTag. I want docs that match at least one or the other or both:

```
return User
    .find()
    .where({
        skillTags: { $in: skillTags }
     }, {
        roleTags: { $in: roleTags }
    })
```

Comment: Do you need `.where` here?  `.find({$or: [{$in skillTags}, {$in: roleTags}]})`

Comment: That works. I wasn't sure if I needed where or find.

Comment: You claim that your second example works, but there's no indication of what property should be in `skillTags` or `roleTags`.  Doesn't look like it does what you want.

Comment: fixed it. cut-n-paste error

Answer (score 1):

This works to find docs that match either a skillTag or a roleTag:

```
return User
    .find({
        $or: [{
            skillTags: {
                $in: skillTags
            }
        }, {
            roleTags: {
                $in: roleTags
            }
        }]
    })
```